# Are we speaking Russian now?

Tags: support

I realize that Russia hacked e-mail that stole the election from Hillary [humor]... that is depending upon who you listen to... but it seems that Goyllo has discovered something that should be considered as a potential problem SE wide. If it can happen once, where else can it happen?

From: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/34044520#34044520

Here is what he is talking about.

[image: I have been accused of many things.]

I have been accused of many things, however, being a Russian commie is not one of them!

[My apologies to my Russian friends.]

My point is this, this could be a simple glitch with Google, I somehow doubt it because Google has never made a mistake, it is more likely an error with SE. Something that the SE folks may want to look into.

***Cudos Goyllo!!***

Comment: The meaning of that russian text is "In Russian", I just do that because I often check how much stackexchange index and how much Google crawl it.

Comment: @Goyllo So does that mean that there is no concern?? Am I crying wolf? Cheers!!

Comment: @Goyllo I have always wanted to take the Trans-Siberian Railway. At one point I thought I would be able to do that. Still waiting. For that reason, I thought I would learn Russian. I have met many Russian people in my life and I have loved all of them! So it would make sense if I took the trip. It would be fun! However, the older I get, the poorer I get and the less likely I will ever get there. Bummer! Maybe if I win the lottery I can swing it. Cheers!!

Comment: May the Force be with you brother :D

Comment: I always suspected closetnoc was a double agent :-)  That is odd that Google's returning the `site:` operator with Russian in it on `google.com`. Good eye Goyllo!  I don't think we have any need to worry about hacking here, we don't really have anything to hide - just the opposite. But if someone's rep jumps 10K points overnight, or they're listed as "President"…let us know.

Comment: "*Google has never made a mistake*" - A bold assertion!

Comment: @Chenmunka Indeed! ;-) I was being sarcastic of course. Google can do some amazing things and at the same time make some amazing errors that leave you scratching your head wondering What the hell were they thinking? Oh yeah. They wern't! Cheers!!

Answer (score 4):

Rather bizarre that Google would index your chat profile in this manner.

We do have a Stack Overflow in Russian, which is what that line says, but no idea why your chat profile would be indexed in this way - probably some error on their end.

FWIW - does the same for my profile:

https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site%3Achat.stackexchange.com%2Fusers%2F23391%2Foded

Comment: Привет мой друг Oded! (translated: Hello my friend...) I thought it was funny, both ha ha and odd. I was just concerned that there was a real problem that SE would want to look into. I have been called everything under the sun except comrade! So this is a new one on me. Cheers!!

Comment: Yeah. That text doesn't show up anywhere in the page source, so why Google went with that is anyone's guess.

Comment: Ah ha! It is Googles fault! I knew it!! Silly G.

Comment: If only we had a site full of experts where you could ask about problems with Google indexing your website.  ;)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - it is a dark art, people don't really know ~:(

Comment: `/users/` is blocked in robots.txt so Google doesn't have the contents of the page available to it.   Some Russian site must link to that page with that anchor text and Google is indexing that information.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - then I'd expect the ru.so page it is on to also show up on the results page, but no such luck.

Comment: It may be low enough quality that Google decided not to index it.   In any case it wouldn't show up for the `site:` search for stack exchange.

Comment: It doesn't show up on a site:stackexchange.com search either, or just by itself (only the chat link comes up).